# How to align field inputtext right?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

How can I align the Text within all fields to right instead of left? I looked throught the API but found only a property for the label.

**Edit**

I know that I can change it by CSS but I am looking for a way to do it with a config option. 
...still hoping there is one...

Comment: css? `input { text-align: right }`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am looking for a ExtJS native way. I noticed that I didn't made this clear and updated my question.

Comment: EXT.JS uses CSS, there's nothing wrong with adding a class name to that element and setting some CSS for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is actually a way to do it in the field's config object:

```
fieldStyle:     "text-align:right;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is sort of what I was looking for.